# Sending stage primaryStage by Socket in JavaFx

Tags: sockets, javafx-8, stage

Is it possible to send primary stage in JavaFX using java socket and draw the exact same user interface in a client ?

Answer (score 0):

**No** you can only send objects witch implementing Serialize interface so because stage Doesn't implements Serialize it can't be sent by socket